# CSS Animation: `backface-visibility` causing cross-browser problems?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-animations

I'm developing a flip animation to show new numbers; it's much like an analog clock or calendar with the hinge in the middle.

The approach is straight forward: have a `div` with:

- The bottom half of the first number on one side
- The top half of the  second number rotated 180 degrees so it's on the back

In order to show the new number, I rotate that whole div around the center of the container, revealing the back of the rotating `div`:
[Number flip animation in latest Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK5oa.gif)

However, in Chrome, the animation doesn't always work. Sometimes half disappears completely until the transition animation is complete and sometimes the old number doesn't render: [Number flip animation in latest Chrome with the bottom of the number not appearing till after animation is complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCRL2.gif)

In Safari 12, it's worse, it doesn't seem to respect `backface-visibility`, even with the `-webkit-` prefix:
[Safari 12 Number animation, the bottom half of the first number is inverted after animation is complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRs68.gif)

Pre-Chromium Edge handles this fine, but new (checked in v83) Edge has the same issue as Chrome.

I've tried messing around with the properties and have looked through other `backface-visibility` questions here.

Here's the code, hover over the numbers to see the flip:

```css
body {
  background: #2e517d;
}

.container {
  width: 175px;
  height: 192px;
  background: #4e9bfa;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.cover {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 96px;
  background-color: #34b58c;
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.container:hover .cover {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.flip {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.container p {
  font-size: 1000%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container>p {
  height: 96px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.front-number-bottom {
  position: relative;
  height: 96px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}

.front-number-bottom p {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -96px;
}

.back-number-top {
  position: relative;
  height: 96px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.back-number-bottom {
  height: 96px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.back-number-bottom p {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -96px;
}

div.front {
  background: red;
}

div.back {
  background: green;
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p>76</p>
    <div id="cover" class="cover">
      <div class="flip front">
        <div class="front-number-bottom">
          <p>76</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flip back">
        <div class="back-number-top">
          <p>77</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="back-number-bottom">
      <p>77</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is this a sound approach that can be easily fixed in Chromium browsers and Safari?

Would a different approach be better?

Comment: Have you tried with `z-index`?

Comment: @Leo, how were you envisioning using `z-index`? I haven't tried manipulating it during animation.

Comment: Doing something similar ( [this](https://i.imgur.com/eNMZC50.gifv) ), I learned that when rotating elements generates unpredictable behaviors for the content rendering, specially for it's `z-index`. In these cases, we should set that index manually instead of letting it render whenever it wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your code is a bit complex. I would simplify your logic like below where you no more need `backface-visibility: hidden;`

Note the usage of two important things:

- the mask that allow me to cut the element and show only 50% of the height (top or bottom). This will make the animation more realistic since each number will have both top and bottom part seperated.
- the z-index trick where I apply a transtion that change the z-index exactly at the middle of the animation (when the rotations are at `90deg`)<sup>1</sup>.

```css
.card {
  width: 175px;
  height: 192px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  font-size: 160px;
}
.card span,
.card span::before,
.card span::after {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.card span {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.card span:first-child {
  z-index:3;
  transition:0s 0.25s all linear;
}
.card span::before,
.card span::after{
  content:attr(data-number);
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top/100% 50% no-repeat;
          mask:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top/100% 50% no-repeat;
  background:red;
  transition:0.5s all linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card span::after {
  -webkit-mask-position:bottom;
          mask-position:bottom;
  background:green;
}

.card span:first-child::after {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.card span:last-child::before {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

/* Hover */
.card:hover span:first-child {
  z-index:1;
}
.card:hover span:first-child::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.card:hover span:last-child::before {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span data-number="76"></span>
  <span data-number="77"></span>
</div>
```

The mask can be replaced with clip-path too:

```css
.card {
  width: 175px;
  height: 192px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  font-size: 160px;
}
.card span,
.card span::before,
.card span::after {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.card span {
  z-index:2;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
.card span:first-child {
  z-index:3;
  transition:0s 0.25s all linear;
}
.card span::before,
.card span::after{
  content:attr(data-number);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 50%,0 50%);
  background:red;
  transition:0.5s all linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card span::after {
  clip-path:polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 100%,0 100%);
  background:green;
}

.card span:first-child::after {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.card span:last-child::before {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}

/* Hover */
.card:hover span:first-child {
  z-index:1;
}
.card:hover span:first-child::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.card:hover span:last-child::before {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <span data-number="76"></span>
  <span data-number="77"></span>
</div>
```

---

Another optimization using `counter` and without setting an explicit width/height

```css
.card {
  margin:0 5px;
  font-family:monospace;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  font-size: 150px;
  counter-reset:num calc(var(--n,1) - 1);
}
/* this will defined the height/width*/
.card::after {
  content:counter(num);
  visibility:hidden;
}
/**/
.card span,
.card span::before,
.card span::after {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.card span {
  z-index:2;
  perspective: 1000px;
  counter-increment:num;
}
.card span:first-child {
  z-index:3;
  transition:0s 0.25s all linear;
}
.card span::before,
.card span::after{
  content:counter(num);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 50%,0 50%);
  background:red;
  transition:0.5s all linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card span::after {
  clip-path:polygon(0 50%,100% 50%,100% 100%,0 100%);
  background:green;
}

.card span:first-child::after,
.card:hover span:last-child::before{
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.card span:last-child::before {
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.card:hover span:first-child::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.card:hover span:first-child {
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="--n:75">
  <span></span><span></span>
</div>

<div class="card" style="--n:5">
  <span></span><span></span>
</div>

<div class="card" style="--n:100">
  <span></span><span></span>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> When using `linear` it's pretty easy but it's more trick with other ease functions. Here is a related question that can help you identify the middfle of ease functions: [When exactly does an ease animation reach its midpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62474345/8620333)

Comment: These flicker if I change the transition-timing-function to something other than linear (ease-out, for instance). What's the best way around that?

Comment: @NicholasWeber read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62474609/8620333 you need to make sure the z-index update exactly at the middle of your animation so you need to find the time when it's at the middle. For linear it's easy because it's 50% but for ease it's different