# Cubic bezier function for finding progress given time and two control points

Tags: javascript, css, cubic-bezier

I am trying to find a JS algorithm to find the ypos of a cubic bezier given the xpos. the first and last control points will be (0,0) and (1,1) and it should throw an error if any of the inputted control points' xpos is less than 0 or greater than 1, just like in CSS. the function will be called like

```js
cubicBezier(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, time)
```

I spent like half an hjour searching it on google but nothing seemed to work.. I only fornd a buch of mathematical formulas when I was looking for an algorithm. Even when I turned my eyes to stackoverflow I couldn't find anything other than complex mathematical formulas and stuff in c++
the top left point is going to be p1 and the other point is p2.

[image: bezier]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62474609/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/63825791/8620333

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/nerding-out-with-bezier-curves-6e3c0bc48e2f/ might help since it has a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
function bazierEase(p1: { x: number, y: number, }, p2: { x: number, y: number, }) {

    const arr = [0,];
    const stepArr = 0.05;
    const stepBaz = 0.05;
    const baz = bezierEase0(p1, p2);
    let [prevBaz, nextBaz, tBaz,] = [{ x: 0, y: 0, }, baz(stepBaz), stepBaz,];
    for (let x = stepArr; x <= 1 - stepArr / 2; x += stepArr) {
        while (x > nextBaz.x && tBaz < 2) {
            prevBaz = nextBaz;
            tBaz += stepBaz;
            nextBaz = baz(tBaz);
        }
        arr.push(linInp(x, prevBaz.x, nextBaz.x, prevBaz.y, nextBaz.y));
    }
    arr.push(1);

    return (fraction: number) => {
        const iLeft = Math.min(Math.max(Math.floor(fraction / stepArr), 0), arr.length - 2);
        return linInp(fraction, iLeft * stepArr, (iLeft + 1) * stepArr, arr[iLeft], arr[iLeft + 1]);
    };

    function linInp(x: number, xFrom: number, xTo: number, yFrom: number, yTo: number) { return (x - xFrom) / (xTo - xFrom) * (yTo - yFrom) + yFrom; }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227300, https://github.com/gre/bezier-easing/blob/master/src/index.js
    function bezierEase0(p1: { x: number, y: number, }, p2: { x: number, y: number, }) {
        const cX = 3 * p1.x;                            // const cX = 3 * (p1.x - p0.x);
        const cY = 3 * p1.y;                            // const cY = 3 * (p1.y - p0.y);
        const bX = 3 * (p2.x - p1.x) - cX;              // const bX = 3 * (p2.x - p1.x) - cX;
        const bY = 3 * (p2.y - p1.y) - cY;              // const bY = 3 * (p2.y - p1.y) - cY;
        const aX = 1 - cX - bX;                         // const aX = p3.x - p0.x - cX - bX;
        const aY = 1 - cY - bY;                         // const aY = p3.y - p0.y - cY - bY;
        return (t: number) => {
            const x = ((aX * t + bX) * t + cX) * t;     // const x = ((aX * t + bX) * t + cX) * t + p0.x;
            const y = ((aY * t + bY) * t + cY) * t;     // const y = ((aY * t + bY) * t + cY) * t + p0.y;
            return { x, y, };
        };
    }
}
```

usage:

```
const baz = bazierEase({x:0.25, y:0.1,}, {x:0.25, y:1,});
const progress = baz(0.5/*0..1*/);
```