# Calculating exact animation delay

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animations, bezier, cubic-bezier

I am trying to animate an svg element as following

**a.** I want to increase the width of the rect and control the rate of animation speed with a `cubic-bezier`value, in this case it is `cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1)`.

**b.** There are also 3 lines which I also want to rotate, each of them **exactly** when the width of `green` rect reaches them at it's animation cycle **and not before that**.

[image: problem]

**What I tried so far**

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62474609/11156131) and my understanding was that in the bezier curve [graph](https://cubic-bezier.com/#0,0,.58,1), for a given output ratio (progression of animation -plotted on y axis), the time ratio (time ratio plotted on x axis) can be calculated, by solving the following equation.

[image: cubic-bez]

Since, I can already calculate, at what phase of the animation the green rect is going to come across those lines
**{50/125, 80/125, 125/125},**
they become the Y value and I can use them to solve for `t` in **y(t)** and pass on that `t` value to solve **x** by passing on t value in **x(t)**, which becomes my time ratio and I can use that to calculate the delay of individual lines.

[image: S1]

This is what the code looks like, which unfortunately does not do what I wanted.

I am not sure whether the math has gone wrong here or something else needs to be done. I can feel that I am close, but not sure what needs to be done here for the exact output.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

//max px to increase the width animation
var mxWidth = 125;

//animation duration of the green rect
var dur = 2000;

//set style of the green rect
var x = document.querySelector("[class=hitter");
x.style.setProperty('--v2', `${(mxWidth/svg.viewBox.baseVal.width)*100}%`);
x.style.setProperty('--dur', `${dur}ms`)


//what are the x corodinates of the lines
var lnX = [50, 80, 125];

//at what output ratio (width increase) the green rect is likely to 
//come across the lines
var progPct = lnX.map(x => x / mxWidth);

//what is the desired cubic bez
var cubicBezCurvVal = "0, 0, 0.58, 1"
    //split bezier curve value
var cleanVal = cubicBezCurvVal.split(',');
//clean space with map -retunrns new array with the function, original array unchnaged
var cleanVal = cleanVal.map((x) => parseFloat(x.replace(/ /g, '')));

//p0
const p0 = { x: 0, y: 0 };
//p3
const p3 = { x: 1, y: 1 };
//p1
const p1 = { x: cleanVal[0], y: cleanVal[1] };
//p2
const p2 = { x: cleanVal[2], y: cleanVal[3] };

const x0 = p0.x;
const y0 = p0.y;

const x1 = p1.x;
const y1 = p1.y;

const x2 = p2.x;
const y2 = p2.y;

const x3 = p3.x;
const y3 = p3.y;

const coefficient_a_y = y3 - 3 * y2 + 3 * y1 - y0;
const coefficient_b_y = 3 * (y2 - 2 * y1 + y0);
const coefficient_c_y = 3 * (y1 - y0);
const coefficient_d_y = y0 - y1;

function getY(prgRatio) {

    const outputRatio = prgRatio /*y value of cubic bezier curve */

    //get all the t values of y of the cubic equation
    var solution_t_y = [
        { sol: 1, cubicBezierProgressRatio_y: outputRatio - coefficient_d_y },
        { sol: 2, cubicBezierProgressRatio_y: (-1 * coefficient_b_y + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(coefficient_b_y, 2) - (4 * coefficient_a_y * coefficient_c_y))) / (2 * coefficient_a_y) },
        { sol: 3, cubicBezierProgressRatio_y: (-1 * coefficient_b_y - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(coefficient_b_y, 2) - (4 * coefficient_a_y * coefficient_c_y))) / (2 * coefficient_a_y) }
    ]

    var solTY = solution_t_y.filter(x => x.cubicBezierProgressRatio_y > 0 && x.cubicBezierProgressRatio_y < 1);

    function getX(t) {
        return Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * x0 +
            3 * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * t * x1 +
            3 * (1 - t) * Math.pow(t, 2) * x2 +
            Math.pow(t, 3) * x3;
    }
    solTY.forEach(
        (a, i) => {
            a.cubicBezierTimeRatio_x = getX(a.cubicBezierProgressRatio_y)
        }
    )
    return solTY;
}

var timeRatio = [];

progPct.forEach(
    (a) => timeRatio.push(getY(a))
)

//get all the receivers
var impacter = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='axisLines']");


timeRatio.forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        (i == 2) ? impacter[i].style.setProperty('--del', `${dur}ms`): impacter[i].style.setProperty('--del', `${(a[0].cubicBezierTimeRatio_x)*dur}ms`)
    }
)
```

```css
.hitter {
    visibility: hidden;
    /*hide default*/
    animation-name: moveWidth;
    animation-delay: 0s;
    animation-duration: var(--dur);
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1);
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

[class^="axisLine"] {
    transform-box: fill-box;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    stroke-width: 1;
    color: green;
    animation: rotate 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1) var(--del) 1 alternate forwards;
    /*rotate 1s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1) var(--del) 1 alternate forwards;*/
}

@keyframes moveWidth {
    0% {
        visibility: visible;
        /*show again*/
        width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
        visibility: visible;
        /*Edit-2 maintains visibility after animation overs*/
        width: var(--v2);
    }
}

@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(7.5deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </link>
    <svg class="layer1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 200">
        
        <rect class="bg" id="bg" width="200" height="100" fill="#e6e6e6"></rect>
        <rect class="hitter" id="hitter" x="0" y="40" width="0" height="5" fill="#92D050" stroke="#92D050"
            stroke-width="0.1" ></rect>
        <line class="axisLines0" id="axisLines0" x1="50" x2="50" y1="0" y2="100" stroke="#ED7D31" stroke-width=".5"
            ></line>
        <line class="axisLines1" id="axisLines1" x1="80" x2="80" y1="0" y2="100" stroke="#548235" stroke-width=".5"
            ></line>
        <line class="axisLines2" id="axisLines2" x1="125" x2="125" y1="0" y2="100" stroke="#00B0F0" stroke-width=".5">
        </line>

        
    </svg>
    <script src="index3.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: It is bad practice to significantly change the example code, requirements and conditions in your question **after the answer is received.**  See edit history.
 So I think not only me but also other developers. Actions such as yours are well analyzed in a topic on the Meta. [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/440057)   
 Suppose you are not satisfied with the answer, it is your right, but then why change the question. Since in this case my answer loses its relevance. Although all the requirements of the question were met.

Comment: I am sorry to put you in such a position and apologies for that. However, the core issue in both versions remains ***exactly*** the same=> how can I calculate the exact point in the animation of elementA when it meets elementB, based on any bezier-curve. Anyone reading this and willing to pursue a `SMIL` solution can still adopt your solution.

Comment: The only reason behind changing my code (major change >animating stoke-dasharry in V1 to animating width in v2) was, I wanted to show (which was missing in v1) what did I do to solve the problem on my own which can probably indicate how do I preferably want this problem to get resolved which is how do I get a better handling on bezier-curve and a better understanding on to track time in relation to progression.

Answer (score 3):

When solving such problems, when several animations are interconnected, it is better to use SMIL SVG (in my opinion).
Since smil has a powerful tool that allows you to flexibly set the conditions for sequential start, pause, stop animations.
If there is a need to further change the logic of the work of many animations, then it is enough to change the logical chains in the `begin` attribute.
`begin="dash1.end+1s"`

The example below runs multiple animations one after the other, but we don't need to count the timings and delays for each animation.

*Animation starts after clicking on the canvas*

```css
#tube {
stroke:red;
}
.axisLine {
stroke:green;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
         

<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="50"  fill="none" stroke="black" />
 <path id="tube" stroke-dasharray="0,200" d="M20,75 220,75" >
   <animate id="dash1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" dur="1s" values="0 200;50 150" fill="freeze" restart="never" /> 
   <animate id="dash2"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="dash1.end+1s" dur="1s" values="50 150;100 100" fill="freeze" /> 
    <animate id="dash3"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="dash2.end+1s" dur="1s" values="100 100;150 50" fill="freeze" />
      <animate id="dash4"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="dash3.end+1s" dur="1s" values="150 50;200 0" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
               <!-- vertical green lines -->
 <path id="line1" class="axisLine"  d="M70,50 70,100"/>    
  <path id="line2" class="axisLine"  d="M120,50 120,100"/>  
    <path id="line3" class="axisLine" d="M170,50 170,100"  />
     <path id="line4" class="axisLine" d="M220,50 220,100"  />
</svg>
```

The example below runs multiple animations one after the other, but we don't need to count the timings and delays for each animation:

- The first animation of the growth of the horizontal line -
  `id="dash1"` starts after clicking on the canvas `begin="svg1.click"`
- The second green vertical line rotation animation starts after the
  end of the first animation `begin="dash1.end"`
- The third animation in order - the horizontal growth of the line will
  begin after the end of the rotation of the green line

```css
#tube {
stroke:brown;
}
.axisLine {
stroke:green;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
         

<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="50"  fill="none" stroke="black" />
 <path id="tube" stroke-dasharray="0,200" d="M20,75 220,75" >
   <animate id="dash1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" dur="1s" values="0 200;50 150" fill="freeze" restart="never" /> 
   <animate id="dash2"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="dash1.end+1s" dur="1s" values="50 150;100 100" fill="freeze" /> 
    <animate id="dash3"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="dash2.end+1s" dur="1s" values="100 100;150 50" fill="freeze" />
      <animate id="dash4"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="dash3.end+1s" dur="1s" values="150 50;200 0" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
               <!-- Vertical line animation-->
 <path id="line1" class="axisLine"  d="M70,50 70,100">
      <animateTransform id="aT1"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="dash1.end" dur="1s"
         values="
          0 70 100;
          14 70 100;
       0 70 100"
  />          
 </path> 
  <path id="line2" class="axisLine"  d="M120,50 120,100"/>  
    <path id="line3" class="axisLine" d="M170,50 170,100"  />
     <path id="line4" class="axisLine" d="M220,50 220,100"  />
</svg>
```

Below is the complete code:

```css
#tube {

stroke:brown;
}
.axisLine {
stroke:green;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
         

<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="50"  fill="none" stroke="black" />
 <path id="tube" stroke-dasharray="0,200" d="M20,75 220,75" >
           <!-- Line Growth Animation   -->
  <animate id="dash1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" dur="1s" values="0 200;50 150" fill="freeze" restart="never" /> 
   <animate id="dash2"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="aT1.end+0.2s" dur="1s" values="50 150;100 100" fill="freeze" /> 
    <animate id="dash3"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="aT2.end+0.2s" dur="1s" values="100 100;150 50" fill="freeze" />
      <animate id="dash4"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="aT3.end+0.2s" dur="1s" values="150 50;200 0" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
               <!-- Animation of rotation of vertical lines -->
 <path id="line1" class="axisLine"  d="M70,50 70,100">
      <animateTransform id="aT1"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="dash1.end" dur="1s"
         values="
         0 70 100;
         14 70 100;
         0 70 100"
      />          
 </path> 
   <path id="line2" class="axisLine"  d="M120,50 120,100">
      <animateTransform id="aT2"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="dash2.end" dur="1s"
         values="
         0 120 100;
         14 120 100;
         0 120 100"
      />          
    </path> 
<path id="line3" class="axisLine" d="M170,50 170,100"  >
   <animateTransform id="aT3"
     attributeName="transform"
     type="rotate"
     begin="dash3.end" dur="1s"
     values="
      0 170 100;
      14 170 100;
       0 170 100"
  />          
</path> 
    <path id="line4" class="axisLine" d="M220,50 220,100" >
        <animateTransform id="aT4"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="dash4.end" dur="1s"
         values="
         0 220 100;
         14 220 100;
         0 220 100"
      />          
    </path> 
</svg>
```

In the following example, I will double the time of 1 and 3 of the line growth animation - `dur="2s"`
***Note***: that the logic of the application will not break, the animations will still go one after another
If CSS animations were used, then timings and delays would have to be recalculated for each animation.

*Animation starts after clicking on the canvas*

```css
#tube {
stroke:brown;
}
.axisLine {
stroke:green;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          viewBox="0 0 400 200" >  
<rect x="20" y="50" width="200" height="50"  fill="none" stroke="black" />
 <path id="tube" stroke-dasharray="0,200" d="M20,75 220,75" >
           <!-- Line Growth Animation   -->
  <animate id="dash1" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" values="0 200;50 150" fill="freeze"  restart="never"/> 
   <animate id="dash2"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="aT1.end+0.2s" dur="1s" values="50 150;100 100" fill="freeze" /> 
    <animate id="dash3"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="aT2.end+0.2s" dur="2s" values="100 100;150 50" fill="freeze" />
      <animate id="dash4"  attributeName="stroke-dasharray" begin="aT3.end+0.2s" dur="1s" values="150 50;200 0" fill="freeze" />
 </path> 
               <!-- Animation of rotation of vertical lines -->
 <path id="line1" class="axisLine"  d="M70,50 70,100">
      <animateTransform id="aT1"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="dash1.end" dur="1s"
         values="0 70 100;14 70 100;0 70 100"
      />          
 </path> 
   <path id="line2" class="axisLine"  d="M120,50 120,100">
      <animateTransform id="aT2"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="dash2.end" dur="1s"
         values="0 120 100;14 120 100;0 120 100"
      />          
    </path> 
<path id="line3" class="axisLine" d="M170,50 170,100"  >
   <animateTransform id="aT3"
     attributeName="transform"
     type="rotate"
     begin="dash3.end" dur="1s"
     values="0 170 100;14 170 100;0 170 100"
  />          
</path> 
    <path id="line4" class="axisLine" d="M220,50 220,100" >
        <animateTransform id="aT4"
         attributeName="transform"
         type="rotate"
         begin="dash4.end" dur="1s"
         values="0 220 100;14 220 100;0 220 100"
      />          
    </path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I am not looking for a smil solution.